# Acceptable Negative Margins?

Tags: html, css

I've created a website using Skeleton boilerplate so that it's responsive and available to mobile users, all pages except the contact page have a **full width background image** but **not set as a background image it's an img tag** and I've given the **content that overlays it a negative margin**.

The reasons for this are:

1. I need it to be the full width and the content; Skeleton boilerplate has left and right margins so that stops me setting the background image on the content.
2. I also need the image containing div to always be the full height of the image, but the image height is not a set size it responds to browser width and maintains its aspect ratio.
3. The image is contained in another div that has a transparent tiled background that overlays the image with diagonal scan lines, this is necessary for the design and I don't want to use CSS3 multiple background images just yet because I want to support some older browsers.
4. I'd like the image to be larger than necessary (I realize right now its a bit too big) so that it's an acceptable quality even on larger resolution monitors.

Now **I'd rather not use negative margins**, I know they are valid code but I've had problems width them in the past and was wondering **is there any other way of achieving the same result without them?**

I've tried using absolute positioning on the img background element, and Firefox for some unknown reason adds a big empty chunk of space at the beginning of the document pushing the whole page down maybe 200px.

The website is www.f3racing.co.uk

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but you could just make a div with the background image set (or just another image tag) then absolutely position it to the top and left, and give it a z-index lower than the rest of the content.

Comment: @Andy thanks for the response, I was just about to edit my question to add that I tried this but for some reason in Firefox with this method I get a massive empty space at the beginning of the document, I've posted in a couple of Firefox forums asking why this is but no resolve just yet.

Comment: I wouldn't say thats a reason to not use this solution, it seems the best way to do it. Troubleshooting that problem is probably better than trying to get a working, sub par solution

Comment: You might be right this may be the only option I'm facing with if I don't want to use negative margins. But the reason I'm hesitant using it is because to me it seems like there will be a similar technique (as in valid but not nice clean code that isn't frowned upon) to the negative margins used to get it to work in Firefox.

Comment: I haven't come across the problem so I can't say for certain, but FireFox normally behaves relatively well and it may be an error in your code that needs fixing or improving, rather than using a buggy hack.

Comment: Do you have the styles for your absolute position attempt?  If you are not bothered about the image scrolling you could try position fixed with a lower z-index

Comment: @Pete I think it should be easy enough to do in Firebug in Firefox change ".newsbanner img { position: relative; }" to "position: absolute" and ".hentry:first-child { margin-top: -450px; }" to "{ margin-top: 200px; }". The margin set on the .hentry:firstchild was pushing not only itself down 200px but everything else too for some reason. I do need the image to scroll, thanks for the response though.

Comment: I always find silly bugs where margin affects other elements too, in that case I wrap it in another div and use padding on the parent div instead of margin

Comment: Excellent idea @Pete I just gave it a go and there is still some empty space at the beginning of the document, I cant seem to see why, no other elements seem to have a top margin that would be affecting this. Another strange thing I noticed is that ".container .column, .container .columns" is floated left and if I remove this float the space vanishes, but the float is part of the boilerplate so something we can't really change. Just thought I'd mention it in case it sparked an idea with someone.